# Negative definite matrix and its inverse

Tags: matrices, inverse, symmetric-matrices, positive-definite

$$ A= \begin{pmatrix} -62 & -158 \\ -158 & -398\end{pmatrix} $$

Is $A$ negative definite?(Is ${\displaystyle z^{\textsf {T}}Az} <0 $  for every non-zero column vector $z$ of $n$ real numbers?)

What can we say above the definiteness of the inverse of $A$?

$$ A^{-1} = \frac{1}{144} \begin{pmatrix} -194 & -79 \\ -79 & 31 \end{pmatrix} $$

Is it negative definite as well?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Have you heard about eigenvalues of a square matrix? I suggest you to take a look at [eigenvalues of a square matrix](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Eigenvalue.html).

The sign of the eigenvalues of a matrix, always determines whether it is PSD (Positive Semi-Definite), PD, ND, NSD, ID.

Answer (score 0):

$A$ is indefinite, since $\det A =-288 <0.$